# How to properly propagate usage requirement through interface libraries in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to make an interface library out of separated include directory and binary path of another directory in cmake. my code is:

```
set(OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS ${opencl_prefix}/include/ CACHE PATH "Opencl headers location")
set(OpenCL_LIBRARIES ${opencl_prefix}/lib64/libOpenCL.so.1.1 CACHE FILEPATH "Opencl library location")
add_library(OpenCL INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(OpenCL INTERFACE ${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(OpenCL INTERFACE ${OpenCL_LIBRARIES})
```

then I use OpenCL library I defined to specify usage requirement of a binary named 'opencl_mult_test':

```
add_executable(opencl_mult_test [[# some sources here #]])
target_link_libraries(opencl_mult_test PUBLIC OpenCL)
```

at this point when I check opencl_mult_test's INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES it correctly points to OpenCL but INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES and INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES both are empty properties so build is impossible. furthermore when I use:

```
target_include_directories(opencl_mult_test PUBLIC ${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

opencl_mult_test can be built. what can I do to get rid of one line code above and still be able to successfully build?

Comment: Did you mean so say INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES instead of INTERFACE_HEADER_LIBRARIES and HEADER_LIBRARIES? I don't think those are valid properties.

Comment: Yes thank you I'll edit now.

Comment: I don't know why this wouldn't work, but it seems like an imported target might be a better fit. Add it as an imported library, then set the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property to the path to the library and set includes with `target_include_directories(INTERFACE)` like you're already doing. I'd be curious to know if you get a different result.

Comment: I did as you said It works. thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Jason Haslam said I made these modification to the code instead of:

```
set(OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS ${opencl_prefix}/include/ CACHE PATH "Opencl headers location")
set(OpenCL_LIBRARIES ${opencl_prefix}/lib64/libOpenCL.so.1.1 CACHE FILEPATH "Opencl library location")
add_library(OpenCL INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(OpenCL INTERFACE ${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(OpenCL INTERFACE ${OpenCL_LIBRARIES})
```

I used:

```
set(OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS ${opencl_prefix}/include/ CACHE PATH "Opencl headers location")
set(OpenCL_LIBRARIES ${opencl_prefix}/lib64/libOpenCL.so.1.1 CACHE FILEPATH "Opencl library location")
add_library(OpenCL UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(OpenCL PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES CXX
    IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OpenCL_LIBRARIES}
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

and now by just:

```
target_link_libraries(opencl_mult_test PUBLIC OpenCL)
```

I can build the binary and it runs properly